# Google Vision API's label detection

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-api-python-client, vision

**Problem 1:**

I'm using `Vision API's label detection` and I'm getting the following error:

> "**HttpError 429** when requesting
>   https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json returned
>   "Insufficient tokens for quota group and limit DefaultGroupUSER-100s
>   using the limit by ID mynumericid@mynumericid."

I'm not issuing to many requests, about 9 per minute, which is way lower than the limit per 100 seconds ( `Queries/100s/User Limit 1,000` ), so I've no idea why this error message is displaying.

---

**Problem 2**

Instead of sending 9 requests, one per image (as I'm using above), I'm able to request then at once on the same request, the problem is that some images **cannot be labeled** and the response doesn't specify which ones, so it's impossible to know **which label corresponds to which image**, i.e:

**The request** with **9 images** to be labeled:

```
 service_request = service.images().annotate(body={
        'requests': [{
            'image': {
                'content': image1.decode('UTF-8')
            },
             'image': {
                'content': image2.decode('UTF-8')
            },
etc..
```

---

**Response:**

The response contains only **8 labels** and the image names aren't specified, so I've no idea which image couldn't be labeled.

Example response:

```
{u'responses': [{u'labelAnnotations': [{u'score': 0.95578641, u'mid': u'/m/036qh8', u'description': u'produce'}, {u'score': 0.917763, u'mid': u'/m/02wbm', u'description': u'food'}, {u'score': 0.7463333, u'mid': u'/m/0270h', u'description': u'dessert'}, {u'score': 0.70616114, u'mid': u'/m/0krfg', u'description': u'meal'}, {u'score': 0.69225645, u'mid': u'/m/0f4s2w', u'description': u'vegetable'}, {u'score': 0.68722612, u'mid': u'/m/02xwb', u'description': u'fruit'}, {u'score': 0.58573318, u'mid': u'/m/0hz4q', u'description': u'breakfast'}, {u'score': 0.52691895, u'mid': u'/m/05cq63', u'description': u'kue'}]}]}
```

---

I'm aware that this question is very specific and I'm just hopping that one of you, with previous experience about this, can share it with me.

Comment: Have you found anything resolving Problem 1 `Insufficient tokens for quota group`. Is it because of many simultaneous requests.

Comment: I never solved this :(

Comment: Using the rest API instead was a better work around for this.

Answer (score -1):

Try rebuilding the "service" for each loop/call to the image, so as to refresh the token